# Find supremum and infimum of a set

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Find supremum and infimum of the sequence
$$a_n = \frac{2n^2}{4n^2+1},\:\:n\:\in \mathbb{N}.$$

I thought the supremum is $1/2$
and there is no infimum because the sequence gets close to ${0}$, but $0\notin \mathbb{N}$.

In addition, I need to find $n$ that  $a_n\in \left(S-0.0080,S\right)$ and $a_n\in \left(I,I+0.0080\right)$.

Comment: If $0 \not \in \mathbb N$ then the infimum (and minimum) is $\frac{2}{5}$ when $n=1$.  If $0  \in \mathbb N$ then the infimum (and minimum) is $0$ when $n=0$.

Comment: Look at $ \dfrac {1}{2+1/2n^2}$ for $n \not =0.$

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the $a_n$ are interpreted as elements of $\mathbb R$ and not of $\mathbb N$ (since they are not even in $\mathbb N$) there will be an infimum. The sequence does not get close to $0$, in fact
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Since the sequence is increasing, the supremum is $1/2$ you will find the infimum by computing the first term.